# How should i bake a normal map?

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

[image]The one of the left is the material with the original normalmap of the material(a downloaded PBR)and the one of the right is used the normal baked by putting the color map of my texture in the displacement(I baked my normal map without checking selected to active)How should i bake a normal map ?(just for the material )

[image]

These are the textures :[image]

In the node editor i just connetced those textures(i changed to noncolor data after i made the screenshot)

Here is the fiel:
[image]

Edited :
I achieved the desired result by baking in blender render.How I could do this in cycles ?[image]

Comment: The downloaded normal map is probably partly hand made, that is, constructed with additional information not present in just the color channels. Reproducing it exactly will be difficult/impossible. For what purpose are you looking to do this?

Comment: I want to create a normal map" in the shape of the uv map"(i want to export my model in unity ).

Comment: If you plug the downloaded normal map into the normal input socket, then it should be used when baking the normals

Comment: If i do this the normal  is blank (is just a  purple texture)

Comment: Hm, is it possible you could [upload your .blend](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/658/599) or a screenshot?

Comment: I am trying to make those in the shape of the UV map because ,i as said above,i want to export my model.I want to make all those maps (diffuse,roughness and normal) like this

Comment: had this same head ache i found the following video by andrew price at blender guru helpful in his anvil series also same process for other types of image files too eg: specular, diffuse, etc [how to bake perfect normals blender 2.79](https://youtu.be/0r-cGjVKvGw)

Comment: Everything in your screenshot looks fine, and if I replicate it here it works for me. Is it possible you could upload your file?

Comment: Sure.I edited the post.

Comment: Strange, all I did was substitute my own texture and it worked for me. Can you confirm [this file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6207/) works for you as well?

Comment: You can explain step by step what you have done in blender ?

Comment: I opened your file, supplied my own normal map, switched to CPU rendering, and baked. If my file works for you, then I'd suggest trying it with GPU rendering and see if that was the problem (shouldn't be, but seems like that might be the most likely possibility at this point). The other obvious possibility is there's something strange with your texture, but I can't think of anything that would cause this offhand.

Comment: In your file all i have to do is to  select the new image in node editor and hit bake ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95605/discussion-between-gandalf3-and-krenk).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you only have one mesh and you want to bake its normal, right?

Then if you want to do that, it's **almost** the same thing as in Andrew Price's tutorial except you **don't check** the `Selected to active` checkbox.

-Create a new image.

-Add an image texture to your object's node tree

-Don't plug it to anything or you may have an error, also make sure that your newly created image isn't used anywhere in your material.

-Select the image texture node you just created before hitting bake and you should get the result that you want.